# How to prevent blank submissions in Cognito Forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

How do I disallow blank form submissions?

I've made the contact fields required, but still receive blank forms.

Comment: Users should not be able to submit a form if a required field is left blank. Would you be able to create a Help Ticket (http://help.cognitoforms.com/request-help) with your Organization and Form name so that we can check to see if any errors or occurring for your form specifically.

Comment: I did create a help ticket . . . any progress?